JPA attribute converter not eligible for auto-proxying in Spring boot 3.3.3
Used to work fine in 2.3.x.  Upgrading to boot 3.3.3, have this message in startup:
[WARN ] 2024-08-26 07:50:16.818 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization() - Bean 'com.test.converter.JPAConverter' of type [com.test.converter.JPAConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

Here is the code:
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class JPAConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Object>, String> {

    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Object> dataObj) {
        // do something and return a string
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String in) {
        // do something and return a list
    }
}


How to get rid of the warning?
Also, on startup there are a lot similar warning from spring's beans, there are a few issues opened in spring's repo but no resolution yet.
Thanks
